# How can I redirect Document root to Magento root?

Tags: magento2, apache2, ubuntu

Ducument root is /var/www/html

Magento root is /var/www/html/magento

I tried the virtual directory like

```
VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento
    <Directory /var/www/html/magento>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But this broke my frontend page and admin page.

Comment: You need Set require all granted: 
<Directory /var/www/html/magento>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

after that static content deploy and flush the cache using this command:

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This one is working for me.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin magento2@test.com
    ServerName magento2.local.com
    ServerAlias www.magento2.local.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento21
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/magento21>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```